# add a number in fish script

Tags: shell, fish

I want to have a function that gets the number of lines of output from a command and adds one to it. So far I have this:

```
function add1
    set num (tmux list-sessions | wc -l)
    echo $num
end
```

Now how do I add `1` to `$num`? (or while I'm assigning the variable)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the `math` command in the [user documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/commands.html):

```
set num (math $num + 1)
```

Comment: You could also do this in the original assignment:  `set num (math (tmux list-sessions | wc -l) + 1)`